# Can't import Image from 'next/image'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I've created a NextJS project, but I'm not able to import the `Image` component. I've already imported other components from NextJS (e.g. `Head`, `Link`, etc.) and everything works fine. Now, I'm having troubles with the `Image` component.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image: Error message]

Comment: which `next.js` version are you working?

Comment: In package.json I have “next: 9.5.5”

Comment: Next.js 10 support that

Comment: @Enricopro update your next js version.